# In Node.js how can I tell when I have finished parsing a web page?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

The documentation has the following code

```
var options = {
  host: 'www.google.com',
  port: 80,
  path: '/upload',
  method: 'POST'
};

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
  console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
  console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
  });
});

req.on('error', function(e) {
  console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
});

// write data to request body
req.write('data\n');
req.write('data\n');
req.end();
```

Whilst the chunks print successfully, I'm not sure how to tell when I have reached the end of the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
  console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
  console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
  });
  res.on('end', function () {
    console.log('The end');
  });
});
```

http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_end

> Event: 'end'. Emitted exactly once for each request. After that, no more 'data' events will be emitted on the request.